# TreeView How to do this?

Tags: c#, sql

```
   I have create table in database name"Group" contains ID,Rank,Name like this:
    ID   RANK    NAME
    1     A      Main
    2     A1     Departments
    3     A2     Companies
    4     A3     Usres
    5     I      Invoice
    6     T      Tools
    7     T1     ChangPswd
    8     T2     ChangLanguage
when I try this query  get the same result
```

how can i make 'A+T'is parent and (A1,A2,A3,T1,T2) is childnode? (in the same table)
    SELECT Rank,Name,
          Rank()   over (order by  Rank) as Rank 
        FROM Group 
    ORDER by ID;

```
//in formLoad
{
DataTable dt;
DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
dt = db.ExcuteDataTable("SELECT Name FROM Group")
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)

        {
            parentNode = Tree.Nodes.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
        }

how can i make 'A+T'is parent and (A1,A2,A3,T1,T2) is childnode? (in the same table)
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the schema of your table if possible.  Change the Rank field to an int that is a foreign key to the ID field on the same table. Then you can easily select the children of a node by inner joining the table with itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do it with hard coding, i dont agree with that, instead of it you can add another column named parent to identify parents for each child.

But answering your question

You can first create the A,T nodes and then look for their childNodes using SubString

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   if(dr["Name"].ToString().Trim() != "A" && dr["Name"].ToString().Trim() != "T")
   {
    if(dr["Name"].ToString().SubString(1,1) == "A")
    {
            parentNodeA = Tree.Nodes.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
    }
    else if(dr["Name"].ToString().SubString(1,1) == "T")
    {
            parentNodeT = Tree.Nodes.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you are refering to A,T as example and you can have more parentnodes like I,F,L you can identify the parents with their lenght,

```
Private Sub populateNodes(dt as DataTable)
{
  populateParentNodes(dt);

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
     if(dr["Name"].ToString().Trim().Lenght() > 1)
     {
      Tree.Nodes.FindNodeByName(dr["Name"].ToString().SubString(1,1)).Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
     }
  }
}

Private Function populateParentNodes(DataTable dt)
{
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
     if(dr["Name"].ToString().Trim().Lenght() == 1)
     {
        Tree.Nodes.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
     }
  }
}
```

I did not tested the code because i wrote it whitout the IDE but i hope it helps you

Greetings